# Evaluating an integral over the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show

$$ \int_0^{2 \pi } \frac{ R^2 - r^2 }{R^2-2rR \cos( \phi - \theta ) + r^2 } d\theta = 2 \pi $$

for any $R > r $ and $\phi $

I dont know if I should use *Poisson's formula* or try to find a substitution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned Poisson's formula, let's try to use it. Note that if in general $f(Re^{i\theta})$ is a function defined on $\{|x| = R\}$ in $\mathbb R^2$, then the function

$$u(re^{i\phi}) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{R^2 - r^2}{R^2 - 2rR \cos(\phi - \theta) + r^2} f(Re^{i\theta}) d\theta $$

defined in $\{|x| \le R\}$ solves the Dirichlet's problem. That is, $u$ satisfies

$$\begin{cases} \Delta u = 0 & \\ u|_{\{|x| = R\}} = f & \end{cases}$$

So if now $f \equiv 1$, $u$ must also be identically one (by the uniqueness of the solution of the Dirichlet problem). So we have for all $R>r$ and $\phi$,

$$1 = u(re^{i\phi}) =  \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{R^2 - r^2}{R^2 - 2rR \cos(\phi - \theta) + r^2} d\theta.$$

Answer (score 2):

I offer two suggestions. Firstly, setting $a=r/R$ and $t=\phi-\theta$, the integral reduces to
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1-a^2}{1+a^2-2a\cos{t}} \, dt, $$
with $a<1$. You could now set $z=e^{it}$, which reduces the integral to
$$ -i\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1-a^2}{z(1+a^2)-2a z^2 -2a} \, dz, $$
which is easy to do by finding the poles and using the calculus of residues.

Alternatively, a useful formula is the Fourier expansion of the integrand: it is easy to show, using the complex formula for the cosine and the geometric series formula that if $\lvert a \rvert<1$,
$$ 1+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n\cos{nt} = \frac{1-a^2}{1+a^2-2a\cos{t}}; $$
this converges absolutely uniformly in $t$, so you can interchange the order of summation and integration:
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1-a^2}{1+a^2-2a\cos{t}} \, dt = \int_0^{2\pi} \left( 1+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n\cos{nt} \right) dt = 2\pi + 0, $$
since the integral of a cosine over a whole period is zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you are lazy write
\begin{equation*}
R^{2}-2rR\cos (\varphi -\theta )+r^{2}=|\mathbf{R-r}|^{2}
\end{equation*}
and use the standard formula
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{|\mathbf{R}-\mathbf{r}|}=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty }\frac{r^{l}}{R^{l+1}}%
P_{l}(\cos \varphi -\theta ),\;R>r
\end{equation*}
together with the orthogonality of the $P_{l}$'s
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{2\pi }d\theta \frac{1}{(\mathbf{R-r)}^{2}} &=&\int_{0}^{2\pi
}d\theta \sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\sum_{l=0}^{\infty }\frac{r^{k+l}}{R^{k+l+2}}%
P_{k}(\cos \varphi -\theta )P_{l}(\cos \varphi -\theta ) \\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\sum_{l=0}^{\infty }\frac{r^{k+l}}{R^{k+l+2}}\delta
_{kl}=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty }\frac{r^{2l}}{R^{2l+2}}=\frac{1}{R^{2}}%
\sum_{l=0}^{\infty }(\frac{r^{2}}{R^{2}})^{l}=\frac{1}{R^{2}}\frac{1}{1-%
\frac{r^{2}}{R^{2}}}=\frac{1}{R^{2}-r^{2}}
\end{eqnarray*}